# Splitting Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a game and I have an array of floats that make a 3D models that I've placed in with opengl. What I want to do is separate the x,y&z coords and make them into a multi-dimensional array. I want to do this so I can adjust the y position in relation to the terrain. The for loop that I have placed in my init function is as follows:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(desert_scene_plainVerts); x++) {
    if (((x + 3)%3) == 0) {
        //x coord
        terrainxPos[x/3] = desert_scene_plainVerts[x];
    }
    else if (((x + 1)%3) == 0) {
        //z coord
        terrainzPos[(x-2)/3] = desert_scene_plainVerts[x];
    }
    else{
        //y coord
        terrainzPos[(x-1)/3] = desert_scene_plainVerts[x];
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on this line:

```
terrainzPos[(x-1)/3] = desert_scene_plainVerts[x];
```

The error goes as follows:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address= 0x10 etc.)
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think perhaps (x-1)/3 is giving a floating point number instead of an integer. Try using `ceil((x-1)/3)` or `(x-1)/3 >> 0`

Comment: Typo? You say `y coord` but you typed `terrainzPos`.

Comment: @KumarHarsh No, it doesn't do floating point arithmetic: `x` is an `int`, and the C dialects won't convert any integers to floats unless one of the operands is a float.

Comment: @cmaster oh dear lord... yes ofcourse, you're right! too much JS has killed my C :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks ok, assuming you've declared `terrainxPos[]`, `terrainyPos[]` and `terrainzPos[]` correctly.  If those are `vector`s, then make sure you `resize()` them properly.

However, your loop may be clearer and easier to reason about written like this:

```
for (int x = 0, v = 0; x < sizeof(desert_scene_plainVerts); x += 3, v++) {
    terrainxPos[v] = desert_scene_plainVerts[x + 0];
    terrainyPos[v] = desert_scene_plainVerts[x + 1];
    terrainzPos[v] = desert_scene_plainVerts[x + 2];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by resize() them 'properly'?

Comment: @DavidGraovac:  Resize them to be large enough hold all of the plainVerts.  BTW, I just noticed what's likely the real problem:  `sizeof`.  I think you likely mean `desert_scene_plainVerts.size()` if it's a `vector`, or `sizeof(desert_scene_plainVerts) / sizeof(desert_scene_plainVerts[0])` if it's an array.

Comment: @DavidGraovac: You need to resize it _before_ the loop.  ie. `terrainxPos.resize( desert_scene_plainverts.size() / 3 );`